# Time in 24 hour format in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the system time in 24 hour format using VBScript. I had gone through the documents and found nothing. I need to compare the system date and time with my data and need to check the differences.

Answer (score 3):

VBScript's [`Date` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is format-agnostic. You can calculate the difference between the system time and some other timestamp using the [`DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function, as long as VBScript recognizes the format of the other timestamp. Example (calculating the difference in seconds):

```
>>> systime = Now
>>> WScript.Echo systime
26.11.2013 12:48:52
>>> WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", systime, "11/25/2013 23:16:52")
-48720
>>> WScript.Echo DateDiff("s", systime, "25.11.2013 23:16:52")
-48720
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WScript.Echo right("0" & hour(time),2) & ":" & right("0" & minute(time),2)
WScript.Echo FormatDateTime(time, vbShortTime)
```